# Python: a fast way to remove subsets of lists in a list of lists

Tags: python, list, merge, duplicates

For example

`[[712, -743, 741, 698],
[673, 688, 712, -743, 741, 698],
[688, 712, -743],
[743, -712, -688]]`

`[712, -743, 741, 698]` and `[688, 712, -743]` is part of `[673, 688, 712, -743, 741, 698]` so we remove the first 2 and only keep `[[673, 688, 712, -743, 741, 698]]`

They are all int 
I was wondering what would be the fastest way to check all list of lists and filter it out
I was thinking to check the abs valu[688, 712, -743]e of all the elements in a list if all of them is in another list then remove it. Also remove the one that is reverse direction and different by a -1

please let me know if that's clear

Comment: so you want to take a list of lists and return a list that is all of the values, not repeated, in the whole list?

Comment: return a list of list that are not part of another.. This is a simple example.. The real list has more other list

Comment: can you give multiple examples, because the example you gave can be interpreted multiple ways and your phrasing is unclear

Comment: assuming all the letters are int type '[[a,b,c,e,f],[a,b],[c,e],[g,h,k,l,q],[g,h,k],[h,k,l,q]]'   return [[a,b,c,e,f],[g,h,k,l,q]]

Comment: Edited title to describe the problem better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def simplify(l):
    i = 0
    while i < len(l):
        s = set(map(abs,l[i]))
        for x in xrange(len(l)):
            if x == i: continue
            if s <= set(map(abs,l[x])):
                l.pop(i)
                i -= 1
                break
        i += 1
```

This removes any list that is a subset of another list in the 2d list. (The set <= operator is implemented to mean ⊆).

Comment: thank alot .... wt about if i want to simply [[698, -653, 655], [-655, 653, -698]] to just one either [698, -653, 655] or [-655, 653, -698].. like if they are only different by a -1 and reverse direction ? I was thinking some condition in the if statement

Comment: @user2388058 you should include all information in the original question

Comment: There, I just took the absolute value of each entry.